# (Android) Looking for pattern for managing multithreaded access to multiple databases that sometimes attach to each other

Tags: android, multithreading, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have three separate databases in use in my app already released for iOS.  The way my app works is on launch it will update 2 of the databases if any updates are detected in a separate thread.  Sometimes it replaces the files completely and sometimes it merely adds new records.

In another thread, these three databases might be accessed at anytime.  This would be ok except that for some queries I have to combine the third database with one of the other databases via attach statement to carry out complex queries.

On some devices, I'll occasionally get an exception that the database I'm attempting to attach to is already in use.  To combat this, I added a synchronized function that closes the readable/writeable database instance of the database I'm attempting to attach to, and calling this before attaching to said database, but the error still crops up on some devices and the solution could obviously still have another thread re-open it before I attach to it anyway.

A nuclear option would be to create some master database class that has everything synchronized but I'd like to hear if anyone else has an architecture they've followed to combat this situation.

Comment: Just raise the timeout.

Comment: Is that like a global setting or something?  The APIs I'm using are through SQLiteOpenHelper, grabbing a db, and executing rawQuery()s.

Comment: [PRAGMA busy_timeout](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout).

Comment: Ya I still feel like that would only mask the issue and not prevent it. Another thread can still come along and steal ownership of the database.

I need something that will synchronously lock a db while another separate db is doing a brief attached query to it.

Comment: SQLite [does not support high concurrency](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html). But it sounds as if your app's architecture is too complex.

Comment: It just is what it is.  Two of the databases are generated by a service offline and one of them is generated by a user with the help of those other two databases.  I know SQLite doesn't inherently support high concurrency but I was able to achieve this level on the long since released iOS app, so I assume there is a way to do so on Android.